# How to queue the list of NUnit test cases

Tags: nunit

Can anybody tell me how to queue up the NUnit test cases.e.g. if i want to run my 5 test cases in 2,4,1,3,5 order how can i assign them to do so? And where?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you'll be violating some fundamental rules of unit testing.  Tests should be self-contained (hence "unit"), and should not have a dependency order - anyone should be able to run any test or subset of tests at any time.

All tests should return any external resources they use to the original state.

If you really need to run them in a certain order, it would be up to your test runner tool to provide that option.  What are you using to run the tests?  And what are you trying to accomplish that you would need an ordered set of tests?

Comment: This is a typical SO "answer" in that it does not answer the question and tells the OP that they are wrong for even asking it.